# VBA hide form from menu

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, hide

I'm trying to hide a form from the menu using VBA; I've Googled this, but everything is giving me the .visible option, however I want to hide it from the groups menu located on the left side. I could just as easily manually do this, however it's very tedious and I can't be going on other user's computers to do so.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest normally you should only disable menus vs. removing them all together, might suggest doing an enable/disable menu item instead..

It should be possible but how much work is it and is it worth it to you?   It isn't clear what your host application is just that you're using VBA.  Might suggest the host application may already allow for customization if so use what it provides.

If the app doesn't allow customizing your menu you can still do it,  just how much work is it worth for you?  You'll need to look at the Win32 way of doing things.  If not familiar with Win32 and menus take a look and start here looking here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977(v=vs.85).aspx) to start learning about menus  in Windows.   After this you'll find [Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net) will be handle to give you C#/VB sample to call what is needed. The VB should be useful but you will probably need to further translate the VB to VBA for your needs.  FYI when starting out a a C/C++ developer back in the day 30 years ago it was anticipated anyone getting into windows might take them a few months, there is a lot you'll need to get up to speed on.  Thus is this feature  really worth it?

Comment: Hello Dano, I have to apologize; I very poorly worded this I think... Please read my changes to the original post